# Open source equivalent to opencalais (Preferably PHP or Python?)

Tags: php, python, text-processing

Is there an open source equivalent of [opencalais](http://www.opencalais.com) - preferably in PHP or Python?

Comment: What's wrong with their [Python API](http://www.opencalais.com/python-calais-python-interface-opencalais-api)?

Comment: I don't like their terms. Its not really open in the "true" sense - I'd rather host the 'service' myself, with full control, rather than having throttling limits and all sorts of other restrictions imposed on me.

Comment: Couldn't be bothered to plough through all the marketing BS on that site. What does it do?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: In very broad terms, it is a 'service' that provides textual analysis functionality; meaning, it extracts "salient" information from a submitted document, and returns the extracted data in a multiple of formats including JSON and RDF. Can be used for data mining applications etc.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it's an interesting idea. It seems to be parsing basic text or HTML content, then wrapping entities in [microformats](http://microformats.org/)

Why don't you just the web API for their service?

Implementing a solution yourself should be straightforward - it's just a case of lots of regexes and microformat templates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems their main service is [**Named Entity Recognition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) with some extrapolations made on top of that. NER is still a research problem in **Natural Language Processing**. This means there's no one-size-fits-all algorithm, though commercial providers might try to convince you otherwise.

That said, Python's nltk [does have some relevant features](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) for the Named Entity Recognition and a [Dependency parser](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/RelEx_Dependency_Relationship_Extractor) would be some of the building blocks of making an equivalent to Opencalais.